# Drupal: how to avoid memory exhausted error message in few circumstances

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using a Drupal website on godaddy hosting with a low php memory limit.

The website runs ok, but I get an exhausted memory error message when I visit a View. Are views much more expensive to generate for a server ? How can I overcome this issue ?

Also, I've noticed I've issues to navigate in the admin pages if I'm the admin user (uid=1): exhausted memory error again.

If I'm just an authenticated user, then I have no issues with that. Is it maybe because I've more permissions and therefore more module are enabled for admin user ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://drupal.org/node/31819 - read about how to increase memory. 64MB or more i recommend to you (96MB or more if you process images via imagecache or other). If godaddy doesn't provide it, increase "hosting level" or change it.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the php memory limit

sites/default/settings.php

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I'm just an authenticated user,
>   then I have no issues with that. Is it
>   maybe because I've more permissions
>   and therefore more module are enabled
>   for admin user ?

Answer = Yes, the extra modules are using more memory compared to a regular user.

> Drupal: how to avoid memory exhausted
>   error message in few circumstances?

Drupal is viable on shared hosting only if you choose a decent host and have a small to moderate user-base. Honestly, GoDaddy shared hosting has a truly horrible reputation. Stackoverflow is a coding site, but the answer to your question **is** *"get a better host."*  :o)

Comment: Can I change php memory limit with godaddy ? How ?

Comment: Depends on their root settings, you would need to ask them.